# Can't Login to my Server via SSH, and the password is correct

Tags: ssh, login, password

I'm using Linode, and I've asked around on the IRC channels, but no one seems to know. I've logged into my server via LISH ([reference](http://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/Lish_Documentation)), and I used the correct password, and everything went fine. However, I need to login via SSH/FTP, and I can't. It keeps on giving me "permission denied". I know the password is correct because I reset it via LISH, and I know I've got the login method right because I've logged into my server before using the exact same commands. I sure hope this doesn't turn out to be some noob issue, or I'm going to be quite frustrated.

Comment: Anecdotal: Once my remote computer was [OOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory)ing due to a memory leak in a long running script. It turned out that part of the SSH/networking/whatever programs were killed automatically. A reboot solved the issue.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to run `ssh` (the client, and possibly the server) with more verbosity to understand why authentication is failing.  For the client, run

```
ssh -vvv username@host
```

On the server end, check the logs. `/var/log/auth.log` will give you a pretty good idea about what happens when you try to login, look for messages that contain `sshd`.  There are a variety of reasons why authentication could be failing, ranging from simple (you aren't using the right username) to more complicated (`sshd` is configured to use the wrong authentication system).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out as soon as I can get back to working on the server.

Comment: I reset my password via the Web Console in Linode, and I was able to get back in. I appreciate the verbose tip. That's very useful.

Comment: thank you, turns out my server also have ssh ip restriction i found out by looking to auth.log.

Comment: Running ssh -d -d -d on the server side I see "Failed password for michael" ... "invalid password for user michael"  But it's the right user and password!

Comment: I had the same problem. Two clean installs failed to connect. I noted that a password that contained a `@` character always failed. When I used a `!` character instead it worked. This might be nonsense but maybe it will help someone

Comment: ...or the log `/var/log/secure`, if is CentOS.

Comment: `sudo service ssh status` on the server will also give you some valuable info

Comment: In my case it was error complaining that it can not open tty file, after reopening terminal - connection were successful

Comment: What was happening in my case was, I had number of keys inside the `~/.ssh` directory and ssh client was trying all the key files instead of password. I found the solution that worked [in unix exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15138/how-to-force-ssh-client-to-use-only-password-auth): `ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=password  example.com`

Answer (score 2):

in my case our IT department had setup PAM stuff with rules that broke my login.
followed @pestilence 's reply to see error, ended up commenting out `AllowGroups` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, which was setup to some IT stuff:

```
UsePAM yes
#AllowGroups <some IT groups>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same incident, I tried all solutions above and they didn't help, the final cause was because i tried to change my shell to fish using `chsh`.

I had console access to the machine, so i made `tail -f /var/log/auth.log`, so i found the error message user is invalid because shell /bin/fish is not found.

I was also unable to run chsh again because of the same login issue, so i made a symlink from /bin/fish to /bin/sh, and i was able to log in immediately.

Comment: Just created an account to upvote this. I changed to `fish` shell and Windows 10 Terminal was failing to `ssh` with `receive packet: type 51` using the correct password. Changing my shell at `/etc/passwd` from `fish` back to `bash` resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different port. Seems that the SSH port the server was using was being used by another service, and I was getting some verrrrry wonky results.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I edited /etc/shadow- with a text editor, as file manager was the only access I had.
Even after I put the original hash string back somehow it didnt work. So after I reset a password with hosting panel all became working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this 73rd line in sshd_config was the culprit. No where found this solution, just struck it with luck. Either comment it out (or make it 'yes'):

`KbdInteractiveAuthentication no`

Perhaps this prohibits keyboard interaction while logging into remote server.