# Cant connect to my SSH remotely

Tags: server, ssh

I have ubuntu 12.04 and I am trying to connect to my SSH server remotely, I get authentication denied because the password is incorrect. However, when I connect to my machine from my local network i.e., 192.168.1.101 and I use the same exact password I used when logging remotely, I connect to my ssh machine correctly .. .any help with that ??

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your router doesn't have an SSH server running and forward the port 22 to your SSH server.

To make sure that your router isn't running SSH, get the local IP of your router using `netstat -nr`. Here is what I get:

```
netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Find the gateway, for me it is 192.168.1.1. Next, try connecting to it through ssh:

```
ssh 192.168.1.1
```

If it asks for username&password, then it has an SSH server. You should be able to disable it from the router's web panel (accessible with the IP we have aquired).

Then, you'll need to forward the port 22 to your SSH server with your router's web panel (accessible with the IP we have aquired).

Comment: no there is no SSH server on the router I know that and I have checked it now again. I feel like the SSH server on ubuntu is like configured to accept connections only from the local network. I don't know how is this ... but this is what I feel. Is there anyway I can like show the configuration ? or any other ideas u got that might help me ??

Comment: Guys please any help with this problem ??

Comment: Do check your /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Answer (score 2):

You can try running the client and server with more verbosity
See this answer: [Can't Login to my Server via SSH, and the password is correct](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110518/cant-login-to-my-server-via-ssh-and-the-password-is-correct)

Also check if there is a line like "AllowUsers username@ip"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the best way, but it works

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

inside change port to 39 (any, not 22):

```
Port 39
```

save and restart ssh:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

when connect use -p 39:

```
ssh developer@37.288.11.11 -p 39
```